# Show that a measure is absolutely continuous w.r.t Lebesgue and an inequality holds

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, radon-nikodym

I have been struggling with this question for almost a week, which was one of the questions in a past exam. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this problem.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of finite signed Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Given $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $r > 0$, let $B(x, r) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}: |x - y| < r \}$. Given two measures $\mu$, $\nu$ in $\mathcal{M}$, define:

$$\langle\mu, \nu\rangle_r = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\mu(B(x, r))\nu(B(x, r))dx$$

Let $\|{\mu}\|_r = \sqrt{\langle\mu, \mu\rangle_r}$. We can easily show that $\| \cdot \|_r$ is a norm on $\mathcal{M}$ (?). Now let $\mu \in \mathcal{M}$ be such that $\mu(\mathbb{R}) = 1$. Define:

$$f(\mu) = \liminf_{r\rightarrow0} \frac{||\mu||_r}{r}$$

Given $f(\mu) < \infty$, then prove that $\mu \ll m$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Moreover, show that:

$$\left\| \frac{d\mu}{dx} \right\|_{L^2(m)} \leq f(\mu)$$

The **hint** to the question is as following: For $r > 0$, we define $g_r(x) = \frac{\mu(B(x, r))}{r}$. We need to show that there exists a sequence $r_k \rightarrow 0$ so that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \|g_{r_k} \|_{L^2(m)} \leq f(\mu)$ and $g_{r_k}$ converges weakly to some $\tilde{g}$. Then, show that $\frac{d\mu}{dx} = \tilde{g}$.

A comment regarding the hint: I think it is possible to construct such a sequence due to the following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326423/help-trying-to-understand-the-proof-of-the-banach-eberlein-smulian-theorem) and the fact that $L^2$ is a reflexive Banach space.

Comment: @geetha290krm what do you mean for $x=0$? you're supposed to integrate wrt $x$..

Comment: @Harry $f(\mu)$ should not depend on $r$ since you've taken the limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as the hint suggests, we have
$$\lVert g_r \rVert_{L^2(m)}=\frac{1}{r} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mu(B(x,r))^2\, dx\right)^{1/2} = \frac{\lVert \mu \rVert_r}{r}.$$
By definition of $\liminf$, there exists a sequence $r_k\to 0$ such that $\frac{\lVert \mu \rVert_{r_k}}{r_k}\to f(\mu)$. In particular, the sequence $\frac{\lVert \mu \rVert_{r_k}}{r_k}$ is bounded. It follows from the above equality that $g_{r_k}$ is bounded in $L^2(m)$. As a result, up to extracting, it converges weakly in $L^2(m)$ to some $\tilde{g}$ which satisfies
$$\lVert \tilde{g}\rVert_{L^2(m)} \leq \liminf_k \ \lVert g_{r_k} \rVert_{L^2(m)} = f(\mu).$$

It remains to show that $\tilde{g}$ is the density of $\mu$. Take $\phi \in C(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(m)$. Using Fubini's theorem, we have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x) g_{r_k}(x)\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x) \left(\frac{1}{{r_k}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{|x-y|<{r_k}} \,\mu(dy)\right)\,dx =\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{1}{r_k}\int_{B(y,{r_k})}\phi(x)dx \right)\mu(dy).$$
Observe that since $\phi$ is continuous, the following convergence holds for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$
$$ \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{1}{r_k}\int_{B(y,{r_k})}\phi(x)dx = 2\phi(y).$$
Moreover
$$\left|\frac{1}{r_k}\int_{B(y,{r_k})}\phi(x)dx\right| \leq 2\lVert \phi\rVert_\infty.$$
Thus by dominated convergence we have
$$\lim_k \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x) g_{r_k}(x)\,dx = \lim_k\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{1}{r_k}\int_{B(y,{r_k})}\phi(x)dx \right)\mu(dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}2\phi(y)\, \mu(dy).$$
On the other hand, by definition of weak convergence,
$$\lim_k \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x) g_{r_k}(x)\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(x)\tilde{g}(x) \, dx.$$
Comparing the last two equations, $\mu$ has density $\tilde{g}/2$. (The extra factor $1/2$ might be a mistake, I'll let you check).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have a small question related to the proof: why is the sequence $\frac{\|\mu\|_{r_k}}{r_k}$ is bounded?

Comment: Also, I would assume that the fact $\mu(\mathbb{R}) = 1$ is not needed?

Comment: @Harry a convergent sequence is always bounded! And you need the measure to be finite at least to apply the dominated convergence theorem (I used that a constant is $\mu$-integrable)

Comment: Sorry for the late question, but by the definition of weak convergence, should $\phi(x)$ be any function in $L^2(m)$ instead of $L^2(m) \cap C(\mathbb{R})$? For the expression $\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{1}{r_k}\int_{B(y,{r_k})}\phi(x)dx = 2\phi(y)$, I think just show that $\phi \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(m)$ is enough.

Comment: @Harry You're right, the definition of weak convergence implies convergence for every $\phi \in L^2(m)$ so in particular for every $\phi \in L^2(m)\cap C(\mathbb{R})$. If $\phi$ is only assumed locally integrable, the convergence to $2\phi(y)$ only holds a.e. by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem (a.e. convergence is enough for what we need since we're just using dominated convergence, but I just wanted to avoid using this result altogether). But you're right you don't need to assume that $\phi$ is continuous for the argument to be true.